# Gallery image does not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> I have implemented the code to check if the number of image files present in the server and then use it for gallery. The number of images are found correct but only the first image loads and does not change .
>
> ```
> var gallerylength;
> var galleryid = 1;
> function UrlExists(url)
> {
>     var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
>     http.open('HEAD', url, false);
>     http.send();
>     return http.status!=404;
> }
> function checksrc()
> {
>     var index = 1;
>     var src = "images/splash/gallery/img";
>     for(index=1;UrlExists(src+index+".jpg");index++);
>     gallerylength = index;
> }
> function setimg()
> {
>      var src = "images/splash/gallery/img";
>          {
>             $("#gallerywindow").attr("src",src+galleryid+".jpg");
>             if(galleryid<gallerylength-1)
>                 galleryid++;
>             else
>                 galleryid = 1;          
>         }
> }
> $(document).ready(function(event)
> {
>     checksrc();
>     setInterval(setimg(),1000);
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line: `setInterval(setimg(),1000);` you are calling the function, must be a reference to it: `setInterval(setimg,1000);`

```
$(document).ready(function(event)
{
    checksrc();

    setInterval(setimg, 1000);

    //or

    setInterval(function(){
        setimg();
    }, 1000);
});
```